# Hardware Prefetcher prefetches single block or multiple blocks?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

From the information related to hardware prefetching here, [hardware prefetching schemes](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8207/prefetchprj3.pdf%E2%80%8E)
there are 3 types of hardware prefetching,

1. Prefetcher on miss : If there is a miss for block n, then it prefetches block (n+1). As per name reflects, if there is no miss for block n, this prefetcher will not prefetch block (n+1). [Also ONLY single block is prefetched].
2. Tagged Prefetcher : With every block , a tag is associated and as contrary to above prefetcher, this prefetcher will always prefetch block (n+1) whenever block n is accessed.
3. Prefetcher with degree K : Prefetch n+1, n+2,..... n+k block.

In some other link, definition of hardware prefetcher says it activates when hardware detects a stride, it prefetch the block according to the stride in advance to stop stall.

Now, my doubt is as follow

According to Hardware prefetcher on stride detection, Hardware prefetcher will prefetcher block at stride distance .

**Question is** will the hardware prefetcher, prefetch 1 block or 2 block or any no of blocks ?

Let me take one example. Suppose I am accessing 0,8,16,24,....Hardware prefetcher will detect a stride of 8 .

Now will it prefetch only block no 8,16,24 OR will it prefetch all blocks 0,1,2,...8 according to Prefetcher with degree K=8 [ 3rd type of prefetcher above]

If hardware prefetcher only prefetch 0,8,16,24 then at later time access of other blocks not effected due to  hardware prefetching, otherwise there will be a impact on access time of other blocks [1,2,3,,,,,7 ] [9,10,11,....]

Here I will access randomly any blocks after access of 0,8,16,24 so there will be no stride detectable.

Any link or help will highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A non-unit stride-based prefetcher will fetch at the given stride and not prefetch intermediate blocks. The point of non-unit stride prefetch is to avoid excess cache pollution and bandwidth waste from prefetching unused blocks, so prefetching as if unit-stride was detected would be inappropriate.

A prefetcher sophisticated enough to handle strides is almost certain to provide more than one stream of stride sequences, so a second sequence (e.g., 1, 9, ...) could be detected and prefetch started while still prefetching along the first sequence. Hardware predicts the future based on past behavior. If behavior outside the first sequence is random, the hardware cannot accurately predict that the other blocks will be accessed soon. (Software prefetch could inform the hardware of such expected behavior.)

In addition, different prefetch engines and policies are likely to exist at different levels of cache. Such would mainly influence fetch ahead distance (to compensate for greater latency of accesses closer to memory), but prefetch engines farther from the processor are also likely to be more tolerant of latency (so more cleverness and greater storage and logic overhead can be applied; cache pollution is also somewhat less critical because outer levels of cache have greater capacity and associativity). (At the memory controller, prefetch within an active DRAM row can be less expensive than random accesses, especially when such avoids using burst chop which reads only half of a full burst.)